# Убрать пустые строки или неразрывный пробел BS4

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

Пытаюсь вывести описание ресторана, но в нём есть символы неразрывного пробела, или что-то типа того, которые никак не удаётся убрать. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как от этого можно избавиться?
upd: помимо неразрывных пробелов, нужно убрать переход строки, чтоб вывод был однострочный, если такое вообще возможно

```
url = "https://www.restoclub.ru/msk/place/39-trattoria-pizzeria"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
reqs = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')
for link in soup.find_all(class_='place-title__header'):
    for link2 in soup.find(class_='place__description').find_all(class_='expandable-text'):
        print(url + '|' + str.strip(link.text) + '|' + str.strip(link2.text).replace('\xa0', '').replace('\n', ''))
```

Вывод: https://gist.github.com/xOrb1t/3a276976079efa5f67665ddad69852ac

Comment: "вывод был однострочный" print(''.join(soup.find("div", class_="expandable-text__t").stripped_strings))

Comment: @СергейШ Ответьте, пожалуйста, отдельным постом, отмечу ваш ответ. И спасибо, что помогли разобраться!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
name = soup.find(class_='place-title__header').text
title = ' '.join(soup.find(class_="expandable-text__t").stripped_strings)
print(url)
print(name)
print(title)
```

Comment: Вариант с `stripped_strings` проще, +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Вместо `'&nbsp;'` в `.replace('&nbsp;', '')` используйте `'\xa0'`:

```
.replace('\xa0', '')
```

`&nbsp;` - это строка-заменитель в HTML и работать будет при обработке строки через парсер HTML

---

**UPD.**

Пустые строки это, как правило, несколько подряд идущих `\n`.

Их можно заменить регуляркой, ища символы `\n{2,}` (от 2 и более подряд).

Или разделив строку на список строк, убрав пустые элементы и заново собрав

Пример:

```
import re

text = '123\n222\n\n333'
print(repr(text))
# '123\n222\n\n333'

new_text = re.sub(r'\n{2,}', '\n', text)
print(repr(new_text))
# '123\n222\n333'

new_text = '\n'.join(filter(None, text.splitlines()))
print(repr(new_text))
# '123\n222\n333'
```

---

Немного отрефакторил код, добавив наработки из ответа

Пример:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.restoclub.ru/msk/place/39-trattoria-pizzeria"
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
reqs = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(reqs.text, 'lxml')

link = soup.find(class_='place-title__header')
title = str.strip(link.text)

link2 = soup.find(class_='place__description').find(class_='expandable-text')
description = str.strip(link2.text).replace('\xa0', '')
description = re.sub(r'[ \n\r]{2,}', ' ', description)
print(url + '|' + title + '|' + description)
```

Результат:

```
https://www.restoclub.ru/msk/place/39-trattoria-pizzeria|+39 Trattoria & Pizzeria|+39 Trattoria & Pizzeria — итальянский ресторан на Новой Басманной улице. Команда Parisi & Co открыла второй проект с международным кодом Италии в названии, основанной на любви к традициям и вкусу итальянских блюд. Стильное пространство оформило архитектурное бюро Remigio Architects из Милана. Здесь можно найти множество отсылок к Неаполю, природным стихиям и известному вулкану: над многими деталями интерьера вручную работали мастера из Италии. За кухню ресторана «+39 Траттория & Пиццерия» отвечает Алессандро Симиоли — шеф-повар, освоивший кулинарное мастерство на побережье Сорренто. Он перенял свое искусство и домашние рецепты от отца и дяди. В Москве Алессандро работает уже более 15 лет. Помогает ему — опытный пиццайло Александр Слуту. Мастер вырос в Неаполе, в пиццериях которого он учился создавать как классическую пиццу, так и оригинальные рецепты в современном исполнении. Основу меню составляют классические блюда преимущественно юга Италии, однако в «Траттории» можно найти и рецепты других регионов страны. Есть также три специальных курса, посвященных воде, огню и земле. В дровяной печи выпекают настоящую неаполитанскую пиццу с высоким мягким бортиком и разнообразными начинками, а среди закусок подают традиционные итальянские антипасти, в том числе свежие сыры (моцареллу, буррату, страчателлу, скаморцу) собственного производства. Кроме того, в «Траттории +39» готовят супы, делают вкусную пасту и предлагают разнообразные горячие блюда из рыбы и мяса. Пару блюдам составляет винная коллекция с лучшими образцами Апеннинского полуострова и других стран. Ее для отдельной Wine Room старинного особняка составил сомелье ресторана +39 Trattoria & Pizzeria. «+39 Траттория & Пиццерия» — ресторан, где гостей ждет любовь к Италии и незабываемый опыт! Текст предоставлен заведением
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! К сожалению, этот способ тоже пробовал, вывод такой же.
Корректирую: неразрывный пробел убрало, но всё ещё переход строки есть. Сейчас подкорректиурую тред.

Comment: @xOrb1t, ну блин, ответил, вопрос как бы решен, а вы дополняете его и теперь мой ответ неактуальный :)

Comment: @xOrb1t, пустые строки это несколько `\n` подряд типа как тут `text = '123\n222\n\n333'. Такое можно регулярками убрать или через функции. Покажу пример в ответе ;)

Comment: спасибо за новое решение, но вывод всё ещё многострочный, хоть и идёт подряд. Идеал - одна строка, если такое вообще возможно

Comment: @xOrb1t, `'\n'` в `re.sub` или `'\n'.join` замените на пустую строку или на пробел - как вам больше понравится. В случаи регулярки последовательности `\n` заменяются на 1 символ `\n`, поэтому в тексте было несколько строк, поэтому поменяв `'\n'` на `''` (пустая строка), у вас всё будет в одной строке. С `join` логика аналогичная

Comment: @xOrb1t, вариант с `stripped_strings` лучше, но он будет работать только для `bs4`, поэтому свой вариант с обработкой строк оставил. Заметил, что у вас код парсера имеет лишние конструкции циклов, поэтому написал отрефакторенный вариант :) Кст, `soup.find(class_='place__description').find(class_='expandable-text')` довольно просто заменяется на css-селекторы, это тоже самое: `soup.select_one('.place__description .expandable-text')`